# Capturando nome de usuário logado na máquina

Tags: java, sistema-operacional

Preciso adicionar em meu programa um método onde irá capturar o usuário logado da máquina e em seguida exibi-lo para o cliente.

O cliente irá rodar o programa, e em seguida o mesmo irá lhe mostrar informações sobre seu computador que deve incluir o usuário logado na máquina.

Existe alguma maneira de se fazer sem ter que usar o `processBuilder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma é com o [`getProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/LoggedUser.java).

Dá para pegar uma porção de informação útil com ela sobre a JRE e o sistema operacional.

As outras formas existentes não são recomendadas. Em geral esta resolve.

Comment: show de bola cara, coisa simples mais ajudou de mais!
obrigado.